# @RequestBody doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I am sending a JSON obj to the server which will populate my domain obj Report.

```
public class CustomReport {String name;
String name;
String email;
Date invocieDate;
Date shipDate;
//...getters and setters
}
```

everything are populated but invoiceDate.

```
public void create(@RequestBody CustomReport report, HttpServletRequest request) {      
      System.out.println(report.getShipDate()); 
      System.out.println(report.getInvocieDate()); // gives me null
      System.out.println(report.getName());
}
```

I checked the request payload from the browser, i think the request is ok

```
{"name":"trace","email":"trace@gmail.com","invoiceDate":"2015-01-01T06:00:00.000Z","shipDate":"2015-01-02T06:00:00.000Z"}
```

my js code is as following:

```
    $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.report.invoiceDate); //got value here
    $http.post('/api/request/submit', $scope.report).success(function(data){
        alert("success");
    }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){});
```

is there anything wrong with my code? anything I could do to debug?

please help, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just for basic check, Once check your spelling of invoiceDate at client side and server side.

Comment: I think your problem is @requestbody could not parse the date. Is the date format you are using is same for the json response?

Comment: @DiptopolDam I'm using the same date as shipDate. but shipDate is populated correctly.

Comment: @Rahul I did check it several times before, but after reading your comment, I checked it again. i found there is a small typo in my domain obj. i wrote invocieDate. so stupid. and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look more carefully

in the JSON:

```
"invoiceDate":"2015-01-01T06:00:00.000Z"
```

in the class

```
Date invocieDate;
```

In both a name should be the same)